# defining href for static resources coming under a context built with spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, contextpath

I am using Spring MVC with spring security. Problem I am facing is with building static resources paths to set in jsp files.

Suppose my app is deployed in context name `ctxt`

Suppose I want to include a `css` file in all of jsp, so I write `href` for it like this `static/css/global.css` . Now what happens, if I access following urls:

1. localhost/ctxt/dashboard (css `200` OK - final url for css in browser becomes = `localhost/ctxt/static/css/global.css`)
2. localhost/ctxt/dashboard/status (css `404` Not found - final url for css in browser becomes = `localhost/ctxt/dashboard/static/css/global.css`)

And if I change `href` of css in jsp to this `/static/css/global.css`. Then when I try to access these url:

1. localhost/ctxt/dashboard (css `404` Not found - final url for css in browser becomes = `localhost/static/css/global.css`)
2. localhost/ctxt/dashboard/status (css `404` Not found - final url for css in browser becomes = `localhost/static/css/global.css`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set resource in context definition like so

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

and reference like so

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href="<c:url value="/css/global.css"/>" type='text/css'/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. I was missing this reference way. But I haven't understood how it really worked. How does `c:url`  resolved it? Could you please explain the concept little more?